# Find the first occurrence of a given column

Tags: multidimensional-array, julia

In the documentation i have found a function `findfirst` which is capable of returning the index of the first element, which is equal to the given one.

In my case, i have a vector (or a one dimensional array) and i want to find the first column, which is equal to the vector.

I know how to do it the "hard" way: With `findnext` iterating over the first row, checking then the whole column. But is there a smarter way, which isn't obvious to me?

Answer (score 5):

Suppose `m` is your matrix, and `v` is the vector.
Then:

```
findfirst(c->view(m,:,c)==v,1:size(m,2))
```

Should return `0` if the vector is not found and the column number if it is. Going down to basic element accesses might be faster, but this should also do the trick.

Comment: Yep, that's the smart way i was talking about. My solution is the c-way of coding i guess :)

Comment: wait, where do you have the function view from? I cannot find it in the std-lib

Comment: `view` is in 0.5+, in 0.4 it is called `sub`. But updating to 0.5 should be a good idea (especially when using anonymous functions like the predicate parameter to `findfirst`)

Comment: dunno why, that lambda without parentheses for the input confused the crap out of me at first sight ... [shivers]

Comment: ideally, in 0.5 you should be able to write `findfirst(view(m,:,c)==v for c=1:size(m,2))`, but this doesn't seem to have the necessary method yet.

Comment: is 0.5 stable? because evryone seems to be refering to 0.4, even the official docs.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way i go now. It does not feel very smart. I am somehow still confident that there is a better way, however i don't see it right now.

Coming from C/C++ and Python my look my look somewhat weird. I have no idea about good taste in julia. Suggestions are welcome.

```
function findfirstcolumn(A, v)
    index = findfirst(A[1,:],v[1])
    found = false
    while index != 0 && found == false
        found = true
        for i = 2:size(v)[1]
            if A[i,index] != v[i]
                found = false
                break
            end
        end
    if found == true
        return index
    end
        index = findnext(A[1,:], v[1], index+1)
    end
    return 0
end
```